# Entity Framework, Table Per Type and Linq - Getting the "Type"

Tags: linq, entity-framework, types, table-per-type

I have an Abstract type called Product, and five "Types" that inherit from Product in a table per type hierarchy fashion as below:

[image: Table Per Type]

I want to get all of the information for all of the Products, including a smattering of properties from the different objects that inherit from products to project them into a new class for use in an MVC web page. My linq query is below:

```
     //Return the required products
    var model = from p in Product.Products
                where p.archive == false && ((Prod_ID == 0) || (p.ID == Prod_ID))
                select new SearchViewModel 
                    {
                        ID = p.ID,
                        lend_name = p.Lender.lend_name,
                        pDes_rate = p.pDes_rate,
                        pDes_details = p.pDes_details,
                        pDes_totTerm = p.pDes_totTerm,
                        pDes_APR = p.pDes_APR,
                        pDes_revDesc = p.pDes_revDesc,
                        pMax_desc = p.pMax_desc,
                        dDipNeeded = p.dDipNeeded,
                        dAppNeeded = p.dAppNeeded,      

                        CalcFields = new DAL.SearchCalcFields
                        {
                            pDes_type = p.pDes_type,
                            pDes_rate = p.pDes_rate,
                            pTFi_fixedRate = p.pTFi_fixedRate 
                        }
                    }
```

The problem I have is accessing the **p.pTFi_fixedRate**, this is not returned with the Products collection of entities as it is in the super type of Fixed. How do I return the "super" type of Products (Fixed) properties using Linq and the Entity Framework. I actually need to return some fields from all the different supertypes (Disc, Track, etc) for use in calculations. Should I return these as separate Linq queries checking the type of "Product" that is returned?

Comment: If anyone refers to this in future, Union, as below, will work. Linq to Entities will write filthy SQL though, and not only that, if you are returning complex queries, Linq will take forever to navigate the expression tree to actually CONSTRUCT the SQL. In my case, the SQL took 1 second to run (500 lines of it) and 3 seconds for Linq to put it together. The way I solved this was ditching TPT for this return and just used a view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really good question. I've had a look in the Julie Lerman book and scouted around the internet and I can't see an elegant answer.

If it were me I would create a data transfer object will all the properties of the types and then have a separate query for each type and then union them all up. I would insert blanks into the DTO properies where the properties aren't relevant to that type. Then I would hope that the EF engine makes a reasonable stab at creating decent SQL.

Example

```
var results = (from p in context.Products.OfType<Disc>
        select new ProductDTO {basefield1 = p.val1, discField=p.val2, fixedField=""})
         .Union(
        from p in context.Products.OfType<Fixed>
        select new ProductDTO {basefield1 = p.val1, discField="", fixedField=p.val2});
```

But that can't be the best answer can it. Is there any others?

Comment: Hello Crab Bucket, thanks for your input again :), you can see I am wrestling with the Entity Framework to get the best out of it. I did not consider using the extension method of Union, I'll give that a crack and see what the performance is like. Failing that, if it is not performant, I'll resort to trying to get this data calculated through an SP or scaler valued function as per @CodeWarriors suggestion. Thanks for the examples too, they really help.

Comment: @MagicalArmchair. No problems - i think a lot of us are working through it. TBH - i've just read the TPT inheritance section again in Julie Lerman's book and although TPT looks nifty i'm sceptical about how easy it is to use? Your question is a good example and there are also issues around inserting a record into an inherited type when the base type already has a record. It doesn't look easy. Seems as if it's easy to get yourself locked into an inheritance corner with this. Just MHO of of course. Good luck though

Comment: The actual set up in the EDM is very easy and from an idealistic perspective, it does make a lot of sense, in practice though I find myself craving for the control of ADO.net, Tableadapters and Datasets. This is probably born of not yet being accustomed to what works in EF. I tried the union approach, and it DOES work, I needed three Linq queries daisy chained together with Unions. When executed, to bring back 20 rows of 35 fields from the DB, from 5 different tables, the entity framework wrote out over 370 lines of SQL!! Perhaps more importantly, on first run, this took 3 seconds to execute

Comment: After doing some tweaking of my Linq, the SQL comes down to 250 rows, which still sounds pretty desperate, however on further investigation it only takes 30 milliseconds to execute, so perhaps I need to just trust the framework a bit and stop obsessing over the SQL it is writing (considering that the SQL team were the ones who actually put the entity framework together). I may still revert to @CodeWarriors solution if performance becomes a problem, however, for now this is actually working well. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

So Fixed is inherited from Product?  If so, you should probably be querying for Fixed instead, and the Product properties will be pulled into it.

If you are just doing calculations and getting some totals or something, you might want to look at using a stored procedure.  It will amount to fewer database calls and allow for much faster execution.

Comment: Thanks for the response @CodeWarrior. Correct, Fixed and the other 4 "super" types are inherited from Product. The calculations are quite complex from a business logic perspective, hence I have been trying to keep that code in C# methods rather than SQL scaler functions or SPs. Could I query each of the 5 types in 5 different Linq queries and then glue them all together to return the data, then on materialization do the calculations? Or is that just nasty? This will be returning an IQueryable, so I am trying to defer execution to the last minute (eg when paging occurs on the MVC site).

Comment: In cases where I had a bunch of HPT classes, I would generally query them all into a List<Object> collection if I absolutely had to.  Then I could perform whatever on them by going through and evaluating TypeOf

Comment: Thanks CodeWarrior, but I want to avoid materializing them as ToList<> is a greedy operator. I can't help but think your option to do this as close to the data as I can is the right one, in SPs or DB functions *sigh*. I'll try @Crab Buckets solution first of creating a Union using extension methods. I presume Union is a lazy method, so it may do the trick...

Comment: Typically for things that may (will) end up making many database calls or getting back a lot of data to perform an otherwise small operation on (arithmetic counts) I create stored procedures.  Less network traffic, less execution cycles, etc.  Let me know what happens as I can foresee this coming down the pipe for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on your model, but usually you need to do something like:

```
var model = from p in Product.Products.Include("SomeNavProperty")
.... (rest of query)
```

Where `SomeNavProperty` is the entity type that loads **pTFi_fixedRate**.

Comment: Thanks for the input @kprobst! This only works where there is a relationship and not inheritance in the Entity Framework doesn't it? So to include the data from Lender I could do this, however the objects that inherit from Product do not have navigation properties for Product as the ARE a type of Product.

Comment: Ah yes, I see what you're saying now. nvm :)